# GRUB2 UEFI booting from LVM on RAID (with XEN)

Tags: raid, lvm, grub2, uefi, initrd

I'm experimenting with booting root filesystem from `LVM` volume inside the `raid` (mdraid superblock 1.x) via `UEFI` with `GRUB2`. Also I'm using `Xen` hypervisor.

From grub command line I can see my lvm volume (ls command) but I got kernel panic due to "unable to mount root fs". I saw a note in [this article](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#Booting_from_RAID_Array) telling it's probably impossible to boot root fs from raid via UEFI, but I don't understand the reason why not.

Is it possible to boot linux with this configuration without the initramfs (which I don't want to use)?

Answer (score 1):

No promises, but: You can try putting the kernel on the EFI System Partition (ESP), or on any other non-RAIDed partition. My own recommendation would be to use the kernel's own EFI stub loader as the boot loader, in conjunction with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or [gummiboot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) if you want a boot menu that appears automatically or that's superior to whatever your firmware offers. Granted, you won't get the benefits of RAID for your kernel this way, but sticking a kernel on a USB flash drive or whatever for emergency purposes shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: +1 for interesting tips. But finally I used initrd, at this moment Grub2 multiboot is working good so I can use Xen kernel and all that pciback parameters. I'm not happy with initrd but it works. For emergency puropes I'm using gentoo minimal on USB and chrooting...

Answer (score 0):

you can't boot from lvm without initramfs, why don't use it?

rationale behind is: lvm volumes has to be activated, initramfs takes care of it, also i think mdadm 1.X needs to be activated too. (0.9 can be activated by kernel itself)

Comment: Yes, the poit was about Grub2 which can see logical volumes (even under RAID), this is very good, but useless while I still must use initramfs due to kernel. I got it later. Maybe in future, kernel'll be possible to init 1.x superblocks. Less or more, as I commented earlier, today I'm using initramfs.